# CreateProcessAsUser not from a service

Tags: windows, service, createprocessasuser

I want to run an application under another user account's (non-elevated) credentials while that user is already logged-in.  Specifically, I want my application's installer (which runs under any administrator account) to spawn processes into each logged-in user's desktop session.  These processes communicate with a service and display windows on the desktop for the user to interact with.

Ordinarily, from a service running as `LocalSystem`, the approach is `WTSQueryUserToken` -> `CreateProcessAsUser`.  However, `WTSQueryUserToken` won't run outside of the `LocalSystem` account (with `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege), which makes that approach fail here.

If the user weren't logged in already, I could just register the application to run under `HKLM\...\Run`, so that any logged-in user will get a copy of the application when they log in.  But if the user's already logged-in, that doesn't work either (at least, not until they log out and log back in again).

I can see two possible answers:

1. You can't do this.  Sorry.
2. You can get a token from somewhere else (maybe enumerate explorer.exe processes and pull the access token from each one?), call `DuplicateTokenEx`, then pass to `CreateProcessAsUser`.  I tried this approach and consistently received "access denied" when trying to `OpenProcessToken` on a process running under another user session, even with the debug privilege enabled and the process opened with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.

What do you think?

If the answer is #1 ("you can't do this"), then what is the recommended best practice for spawning non-elevated processes to mediate between a service and the user?  Is it best practice for the service to spawn these processes into each session via CreateProcessAsUser?  Or is it best practice for the non-elevated processes to be run separately (e.g. via `HKLM\...\Run` or `HKCU\...\Run`)?

Comment: One obvious workaround is to install and start a service on the fly so that you can call WTSQueryUserToken from SYSTEM context.  You could delete the service again once your work is done.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the simplest workaround, if (A) there's no way to do this from a non-service caller (e.g. an installer), and (B) it isn't bad practice to do it this way!

Comment: (A) I'm not sure why you're getting access denied opening the process tokens, but enumerating processes is an awkward approach at best so personally I'd suggest sticking with WTSQueryUserToken which is documented to only work when you are SYSTEM.

Comment: (B) There's precedent; Microsoft software such as psexec and Process Monitor work by installing services on the fly.

Comment: I'm more concerned that it might be bad practice to run applications this way at all; that it might be better practice from a Vista Session 0 Isolation perspective to register them to run from HKLM\...\Run rather than spawning them from a service at all.